# What is the meaning of 'sanitize-utf8' in syslog-ng configuration flags

Tags: syslog-ng

The documentation of syslog-ng says that this flag converts `non-utf8` input to a valid `'escaped form'.`
Does `'escaped form'` mean that the rest of the part that is not `utf8` is removed or does it mean that the part that is not `utf8` is converted to `utf8`?
And if you add this flag to `syslog-ng.conf`, `syslog-ng` will not run.
[image]
The error code is as follows.
[image]

Why does the execution of `syslog-ng` fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the received message contains invalid UTF-8 sequences, the `sanitize-utf8` flag replaces them with a binary-escaped format, for example, `\xAB`.

The `sanitize-utf8` flag is available starting from syslog-ng v3.7.1.